# Is there a css equivalent to android hint?

Tags: android, css

In an Android layout xml file one can do something like this ...

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/username"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/username" />
<EditText android:id="@+id/password"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:hint="@string/password" />
```

which results in a GUI that looks like this: [image: screenshot]

How would I create that same effect for a HTML form with CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `placeholder` HTML5 attribute, for example:

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" />
<input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
```

Most browsers are compatible with this feature, except Internet Explorer (see comment by jcater). You can use, for example, [jquery-placeholder](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder) to add support for legacy browsers (even IE6!).

Comment: Note that IE (except maybe 10?) does not support this attribute. Nor does Firefox < 4.0 (if that's relevant.)

Comment: wow! thanks for the quick answer, aromero! and placeholder is just the thing I need.